Why are Object mods and Edit mods different?
I edit normals and noticed that in Edit mode and Object mode the appearance is different and I don’t know why.


File

hello could you please share your objects? https://blend-exchange.com/

@moonboots I trimmed it as best I could but it was still too big. Used Google Drive

Do you have an active modifier on the object ? In edit mode by default modifiers are disabled

@Gorgious I have no active modifiers

I don’t know why but I had the shape key selected and when I switched to edit mode the form key was selected automatically

your link asks for an authorization
